# Add padding to tabs React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is there a way to add padding to the tabs I have? This is the plugin that I use h[ttps://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view)

I read the documentation and the issues in the project to see if I find anything but no luck.

Comment: Padding to what part? The tabs on top, or the actual tab content...?

Comment: @Li357 The tabs on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Styling/customizing is available in that plugin. There are two ways to do it as follows:
1] If you want to add padding to your entire TabBar, then this is to be done as follows:

```
<TabBar
  {...props}
  indicatorStyle={styles.indicator}
  style={styles.tabbarStyle}
/>
```

2] If you want to add padding to your tabs, then this is to be done as follows:

```
<TabBar
  {...props}
  indicatorStyle={styles.indicator}
  tabStyle={styles.tabsStyle}
/>
```

You need to add your "tabbarStyle" or "tabsStyle" accordingly. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the plugin you're using but have you tried this kind of trick ?

```
render() {
    const style = {
        padding : '3em',
    }
    return (
        <MyComponent style={style}>
            ...
        </MyComponent>
    );
}
```